# Open large text file (300GB) in text editor

Tags: text-files, text-editor, genome

I have 300 GB text file that contains genomics data and I want to open it. What text editor can I use?

Also, I want to compare two genomics data text files "line by line" of the same big size "hunderds of GB" to extract the newly added sequences.What is the sufficient way?

Thanks,

Comment: On what platform? Mac? Windows? Linux?

Comment: 300GB is a huge amount for a human to manipulate or think about -- is there some actual objective? If, for example, you're looking to search for patterns, then there are tools like `grep` which might help you. If you explain your goal, people will be able to help you find the right tool.

Comment: @Steve Cooper I want compare the two files to extract the newly added sequences. What is grep?

Comment: "grep searches input files for lines containing a match to a given pattern list. When it finds a match in a line, it copies the line to standard output (by default), or produces whatever other sort of output you have requested with options." e.g. `grep "gattaca" sequence.dna` would print out every line in sequence.dna that contained the 'phrase' `gattaca`.

Comment: You might have luck with a file comparison tool, or 'diff' tool, such as FC: http://www.howtogeek.com/206123/how-to-use-fc-file-compare-from-the-windows-command-prompt/ Which I think will only show you the differences between two files. If you have new vs old, and new is the same as old but longer, it'll show you just the content added to the new file.

Comment: @Steve Cooper your last comment will help me a lot. I want exactly what you are type in last comment. Is really that available? what can I do? which programming language to use?

Comment: @Steve Cooper  I want a script not a program

Comment: If you install Cygwin to get Unix-like tools on Windows, it should have a `diff` command you can use, though I'm not sure how well it will handle 300GB files.

Comment: Someone care to make a comment into an answer? My OCD hits pretty hard when I see a question that interests me with answers in comments  :)